# How to show Text depending of Image and Image's position

Tags: android, string, image, settext

I  have an array of `Image` ID's

```
        public Integer[] deckIDs = {
        R.drawable.bashnya,
        R.drawable.blazhenstvo,
        R.drawable.borba,
        R.drawable.card_tarot,
        R.drawable.deystvie,
        R.drawable.odinochestvo,
        R.drawable.opasnost,
        R.drawable.osoznanie,
        R.drawable.otshelnik,
        R.drawable.pamyat,
        R.drawable.pechal,
        R.drawable.peremirie,
        R.drawable.pobeda,
        R.drawable.pomoshch,
        R.drawable.poveshevyi,
        R.drawable.predlagaushchyi,
        R.drawable.presyschenie
};
```

I place these `Images` in  `ImageViews`  with a random

```
    Random card1 = new Random();
    int card1_value = card1.nextInt(16);
    int card2_value = card1.nextInt(16);
    int card3_value = card1.nextInt(16);
    int card4_value = card1.nextInt(16);
    int card5_value = card1.nextInt(16);

    card1_image.setImageResource(deckIDs[card1_value]);
    card2_image.setImageResource(deckIDs[card2_value]);
    card3_image.setImageResource(deckIDs[card3_value]);
    card4_image.setImageResource(deckIDs[card4_value]);
    card5_image.setImageResource(deckIDs[card5_value]);
```

Also I  have 5  `TextViews` and a lot  of `strings`  like

```
<string name="card1_1">card 1 - text 1</string>
<string name="card1_2">card 1 - text 2</string>
<string name="card1_3"">card 1 - text 3</string>
<string name="card1_4"">card 1 - text 2</string>
<string name="card1_5"">card 1 - text 5</string>
<string name="card2_1"">card 2 - text 1</string>
<string name="card2_2"">card 2 - text 2</string>
...
```

And I  need to  show  one  of the `string`, depending on  what  `image` from  `array` I've got, and in what `position` (1 of 5) it has placed. For example, one of the  `Images` make  `card 1 - text 1` if it is in first position, and `card 1 - text 2`  if it is in seconds one. And so  on

Hope you understand clearly my  problem and you'll  help  me, because I stuck because of my weak programming skills.

I need to add, that there will be much more `Images` (near 80) and I hope, it possible to set text, depending on `string-name`  and `res id`, like

```
           <string name="card44"">card 44 - text 1</string>

           R.drawable.card44
```

There is a whole problem in this point. I just  even don't  know how to google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  decided my problem  this way:
`card_value` - random  `int`  for getting name of card from `deckIDS` array. This  name is equal to the one  of  `array`'s name  in  `strings.xml`. With  method  `getIdentifier` I get  `string`  value.

```
   String fortune_1 = getResources().getResourceEntryName(deckIDs[card1_value]);

    int resId_1 = getResources().getIdentifier(fortune_1, "array", getPackageName());

    String[] text_of_fortune_1 = getResources().getStringArray(resId_1);
```

Hope  it will be usefull.

Answer (score 0):

So to me it sounds like you have five "cards", and each card has a position. You need to be able to produce a string that contains the card number and the card position.

You could make a class called "card" and have it have the properties:

```
int position;
int cardNumber;
int arrayPosition;

public card(int pos, int card, int arraypos){
  position = pos;
  cardNumber = card;
  arrayPosition = arraypos;
}
```

Have a function inside of the class that can generate the string you are looking for:

```
public string getCardString(){
  return String.format("card %1$d - text %2$d", cardNumber, position);
}
```

The above method `getCardString()`will produce a string like the one you are looking for (i.e. "card 3 - text 2").

Then you could programmatically set the value of your textview in your code using  the `setText()` property. I.e. `textviewX.setText(cardX.getCardString());`